# iframe contents size

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I am using an `iframe` inside a `div` and I noticed one strange thing, the view looked zoomed-out in the iframe, as in the text looks smaller than it would on a separate page.

Why is that and how can I make it rhe same size as normal?

Code for iframe:

```
function SetContent(link) {
            document.getElementById('lowerContent').innerHTML =
         "<iframe frameborder='0' src='" + link + "' width='100%'" + " height='" + (screen.height - 100) + "px'";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 'lowerContent' is the div, one issue is you don't seem to be closing the iframe. don't forget to add ....

```
"></iframe>"
```